# Append to the list in c

Tags: c, list, linked-list

What is the correct way to append to a list in c? Ive been searching everywhere and everytime I try it myself I fail.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char* groupName;
    int groupSize;
    boolean status;
    struct node* next;
} node;

void add(struct node * *head)
{
    struct node* temp=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->groupName=name;
    temp->groupSize=size;

      if ((*head) == NULL) {
          (*head) = temp;
          (*head)->next = NULL;
      } else {
            struct node* ptr = (*head);  //dont change head pointer, so make variable to keep track

            while (ptr != NULL) ptr= ptr->next; //go until the end of the list

            (ptr->next) = temp; //add this new data to the end of the list
            temp->next = NULL; //null becomes end of list
      }
}
```

call (in main():

```
add(&head);
```

Comment: We need to see more code than this to answer it well. At least show us your struct and where head is defined.

Comment: it's `bool` not `boolean`

Comment: Title says "prepend" and question contents say "append". Those are two very different operations on a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem probably lies in this line of code:

```
   while(ptr!=NULL) ptr= ptr->next; //go until the end of the list
```

You change `ptr` until it's equal to `NULL`, which most definitely isn't what you want, since you dereference `ptr` right after the loop.

Change it to

```
   while(ptr->next != NULL) ptr = ptr->next;
```

and see if that works. Remember: you are interested in the node that doesn't yet have the next node (so you can insert it).

Comment: I will select this answer in 7 minutes(wont let me now), this worked! Now how can I print my list in order of first submitted to last submitted?

Comment: @user3507072 the easiest way IMO would be to use recursion, first "process" the tail of the list and then print the head.

Comment: Go ahead and select it now, it's absolutely the right answer.  Anyone else will just have to parrot it in their own words.  Basically, you need to add the node to the last element (ptr->next == NULL) not the NULL element!

Comment: as an addendum, the line temp->next = NULL; can be moved into an if statement, and then you could have the option of adding another linked list to the end of your linked list.